# Why is it possible to divide by 0 in wheel theory?

Tags: reference-request, education

I have been looking into wheel theory and have been wondering how it is possible to divide by 0 in it. Also, what are some good books for learning about wheel theory?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory and the references there.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think it appeared because of fact that multiplicative inversion of real numbers is only a partial function. In wheel theory we add two numbers to the real ones. Now, division is always possible. We now have a field !!!

Hope I helped, but there are a lot of websites that can help you if you google it ;)